# How to solve base64 encoding result is spliting into two lines in android

Tags: android, base64

I have encode the strings in my project. Encoding is working fine. But the problem is base64 code is split into two sentence. I need this in one single line. My code is here

```
 byte[] data = null;
    try {
        data = details.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.d("base64 code",base64);
```

Result is

> 08-01 17:23:43.738 23517-24634/? D/base64 code: eyJncm91cF9pZCI6IjgiLCJtb2JpbGVfbm9fb3JfZW1haWxfaWQiOiIwODE3MzkwMDU4IiwicGlu
>   08-01 17:23:43.738 23517-24634/? D/base64 code: IjoiNzMxODI1In0=

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specific **NO_WRAP** on your encoding/decoding operations

[Check the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html)

> NO_WRAP Encoder flag bit to omit all line terminators (i.e., the
>   output will be on one long line).

```
 byte[] data = null;
    try {
        data = details.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    Log.d("base64 code",base64);
```

Comment: Also, I have seen a bunch of people asking the same around. If this answer fits your needs, please accept it as correct so others may use it too! Regards